# VB.NET site (with local IIS & SQL Server) movement on godaddy: how to set up connectionstring?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, iis, web, web-hosting

I've developed my first web site with SQL Server for data entering.

It is working perfectly on a local PC, and I have a question about uploading the site to Godaddy.

It is opened but when I'm trying to login (or create new login), the following error appears:

> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The user name or password is incorrect
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential creden ....

I think that it is caused by the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=n1nwvsddcsdb023.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net;User ID=testUser;Password=test57;Initial Catalog=DataB"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=n1nwvsddcsdb023.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net;User ID=testUser;Password=test57;Initial Catalog=DatabaseB" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Could you advise how it should be set up?

Comment: When you setup MS SQL, goDaddy gives you the connection string

Comment: many thanks for prompt feedback, it looks clear for my base DataB (where is tables with entered data), i think major question is DatabaseB, where i placed Users logins, groups, procedures (via Web Administration Tool), how it should be connected?

Comment: the question should be simple